# Name for a vector that cannot be removed from a set without changing the span

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

Consider the set

$$S=\left\{\begin{bmatrix}2\\3\\4\end{bmatrix},
\begin{bmatrix}1\\2\\0\end{bmatrix},
\begin{bmatrix}2\\4\\0\end{bmatrix}\right\}$$

Either the 2nd or 3rd vector can be removed from $S$ without changing $span(S)$, but the first vector is critical to maintaining the span.  Is there a name for a vector whose removal from a set would change the span of the set?

Comment: I would be inclined to call it a "redundant basis", but I will wait for someone with more authority to answer this.

Comment: Do we not just call such a vector ``linearly independent''?

Comment: I would call the 2nd and 3rd vectors redundant, not the 1st vector.  I'm looking for a name for the 1st vector.

Comment: @AlkaKadri I haven't seen individual vectors referred to as "linearly independent," only sets of vectors.  Set S is linearly dependent; removal of the 2nd or 3rd vector would leave a linearly independent set of two vectors.

Comment: You can certainly describe individual vectors as being "linearly independent" with respect to other vectors. For example, I would say that the first vector in $S = \{v_1, v_2, v_3\}$ is linearly independent from the other two since $av_1 = bv_2 + cv_3 \Rightarrow a = b = c = 0$.

Comment: For linear matroids it would be called a coloop (also called an isthmus).